# iOS OpenglES 3.0 rendering to texture fails with depth attachment

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer, fbo, depth-buffer

Rendering into texture in my mobile app works fine when the rendertarget texture has no depth attachment. When I add a depth attachment, it stops working on iOS. Apparently can't switch back to the original render target or it's attached depth buffer, and the image of the freezes, sound continues. It works fine on Android.

//Setting up:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_APPLE, &backbuffer); 
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING,&backbuffer); // tried both


glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthbuffer);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,resx,resy,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, resx, resy);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);


GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

// render into it

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glViewport(0, 0, resx, resy);
  ...
```

// continue rendering onto main screen:

```
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, backbuffer); 
     glViewPort(0,0,screenX,screenY);
```

// apparently doesn't change back to backbuffer, if there is a depth attachment

---

Update:
Found the solution:
Have to unbind the Renderbuffer once you are done attaching it to the new framebuffer. Strangely Android and Linux doesn't care about leaving the Renderbuffer bound.

```
GLint origRenderBuffer;
glGetIntegerv(GL_RENDERBUFFER_BINDING,&origRenderBuffer);
.....// create FBO with attachment here.
glBindRenderBuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,origRenderBugger);
```

Comment: What does `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` return? Do you clear the depth buffer of the framebuffer?

Comment: It returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE. I clear the depth buffer of the FBO and the main render target too.